# UPS shipping option sort order defaults to most expensive

Tags: shipping, magento-community, ups

We offer a handful of UPS shipping options, they show up on the checkout page lest expensive to most expensive, however the redo button defaults to the most expensive. I would like it to default to which ever is the least expensive option.

Comment: Magento does not select any options by default. Are you using any shipping extension?

Comment: No we are not using any shipping extensions. Just the standard Magento format.

Comment: If you check the fresh magento install, you'll see the methods inside one carrier are sorted from lowest to highest. So it has something todo with your extensions or custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

All Carriers in Magento default from lowest price to highest price.